# Ubuntu 18.04.2 Zoom Screen Part options

Tags: 18.04, accessibility

I've switched over from Windows to Ubuntu, in Windows I used the built in magnifier in docked mode, giving me a resizable magnified block at the top of the screen, and it's integrated into the window system so that other windows that are opened always maximize to the bottom of the magnifier.

I've tried using the built in zoom feature, but the only options is to Full Screen, Top Half, Bottom Half, Left Half and Right Half:

[image: Ubuntu Zoom Screen Part options]

The Top Half option is the most useful, but I would have liked an option to specify a percentage, as I can not give up half of my horizontal screen space, as I use it for context of the page/window I am on.

I've also tried KMag, which works alright, however it's a just another window, and as such, other windows can overlap it.

Does anyone know how I can get my most used Windows feature on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

I just installed kmag v1.-00 on Ubuntu 19.04 and it's default setting is view, stay on top, which is does do.
try right click on its mag area, settings, stays on top